# Multi-Sophont Alliance, Episode 1: Is It Even Possible?

Tags: alternate-history, culture, interspecies-relations

This question, if not the entire series, is based on the premise behind this painting by Dylan Bajda:

[image]

[Source](https://sites.google.com/site/worldofserina/the-ultimocene-250-million-years/the-fishers-plea)

Set in the world of Serina, the creatures on the boats are called "gravediggers" whereas the whale-like beings intercepting the boat are "porplets", both of whom are distant descendants of domestic canaries that have taken on different evolutionary paths, yet both species share one same trait--both are sophont.  In the context of the painting, one culture of porplets called "fishers" are under attack from the "warmongers", and they believed that some essence of their mythology--the gravediggers--might be their only help.  At first, it was quite an awkward language barrier (the expressions on the gravediggers' faces really sell this picture), but it has since evolved into an alliance.  There was no domestication involved, nor was there any taming.

Earth itself is also a multi-sophont world.  Apart from us humans, there are also corvids, canids, elephants, pigs, dolphins, New World monkeys, even the humpback whale, if recent hypotheses of altruism are to be confirmed.  In an alternate history scenario, could humans ever develop alliances with any if not all of these other sophonts?

Comment: What makes you think there would be any barrier to developing alliances? It seems like if you want your world to have alliances between races that's entirely within your discretion as a worldbuilder. You may want to add a description of "recent hypotheses of altruism" since your question seems to hinge on them.

Comment: There would be lots of conflict if the groups shared environmental niche The more different the niche the easier is to avoid conflicts.

Comment: what do you mean by alliance? Defensive military alliance? Those generally come well after trading is happening.Trading can occur without alliances//treaties/ formal governmental recognition.

Comment: This seems rather opinion-based.

Comment: @MontyWild  How?

Comment: It would all depend on the psychology and culture of the humans involved.  Not having been given this data, it is a matter of opinion if the humans involved would or wouldn't form an alliance.

Comment: "Earth itself is also a multi-sophont world." Do you mean actual Earth (you literally consider dogs sophonts) or a fictional earth where the animals you list are smarter than they are in real life?

Comment: @SeanOConnor  The actual Earth.

Comment: So you're asking if its possible for man to befriend canids and vice versa in real life? Just confirming you weren't being ironic or sarcastic?

Comment: @SeanOConnor  I don't kid.

Comment: OK. I submit that the answer is: We already are allied with dogs, and factions of most of the others, so yes, given an alternate history we could be too.

Comment: No, we are not allied with dogs.  We domesticated them.  It's not the same.

Comment: How is it different? They like us, we like them, they defend us, we defend them. It's even intergenerational. What's the missing essential ingredient? Non rhetorical question, what constitutes an alliance?

Comment: If you read the Daydreamer Saga (link in the description), you will find that the gravediggers did not domesticate the daydreamers, nor vice versa.  No, they formed an alliance, which is more egalitarian than domestication.

Comment: I'm would hope that you can explain the difference to the people you're asking a question of, when it's central to the question. Telling us to read a novel isn't helpful. Is it 'any friendship except domestication'? Or is there a definition? Without some clarity, we're wasting time and effort.

Comment: In that story, the species involved were intelligent enough to have a desire to want to preserve their society, not just themselves as individuals. Canids, etc don't (and aren't really sophonts).

Comment: this question could be a better question for the site if it contained more information and was much more clear about what it is asking. but in truth the answer is always going to be "maybe". humans have only interacted with sophonts they could breed with and who occupied the exact same ecological niche, and we are not even sure how that turned out.

Comment: @SeanOConnor an alliance requires the ability to recognize it is an alliance and that they can choose not to follow it. Dogs lack both.

Comment: @John Gee, John, if only someone had turned this train of thought into an answer. Maybe it would conclude, "If we're excluding domestication as a legitimate alliance as the OP has stated in comments, then the answer is no for those species".

Answer (score 2):

**Alliances are bases on something common**

- **Common fear**: There is a threat from an enemy to different groups.
  These groups will make an alliance e.g. Alliances in WW-I and WW-II,
  NATO, UNO, sharing vaccine in an epidemic.
- **Common interest or greed**: Economic interest, trading, Scientific research, grabbing resources e.g. EU.
  International space station, UNO, America and
  Australia as told by @Daron.
- **Common ideology**: Alliances based on religion e.g. crusades.

**Conclusion**

Is there anything from above between humans and any of these sophonts? If YES, they will make an alliance. If NO, then no alliance.

There is no such information in your question, so it seems that there will be **no alliance**.

Remember one thing (as told [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0007681317300915))

> For alliances to sustain themselves, the synergies that are generated
> between partners must be greater than the conflicts that drive them
> apart.

Answer (score 0):

**Impassible Terrain**

Of course people cannot form alliances with different species of sentient creatures. They cannot even form alliances with other humans from different places. Case and point, America and Australia. The Europeans moved in there and murdered all the native inhabitants, and took all their land.

Fortunately the humans cannot murder all the Gravediggers and Porplets, because their lands are steep cliffs and deep oceans respectively. This is a problem for the humans but not for the flying Gravediggers and swimming Porplets.

The other creatures live in places the humans have no hope to take over. There is no incentive to murder them all. Thus there is a possibility for trade and amicable relations to develop.